# WooCommerce: Need a working snippet to disable email notifications for completed free orders

Tags: woocommerce

I have some free courses on my site and I would like to disable email notifications for completed order on free products. Tried this snippet but not working on Woo 7.7.2.
I would appreciate if someone could make one that works.

https://www.businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-disable-customer-order-email-for-free-orders/

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_recipient_customer_completed_order', 'bbloomer_disable_customer_order_email_if_free', 10, 2 );
  
function bbloomer_disable_customer_order_email_if_free( $recipient, $order ) {
    $page = $_GET['page'] = isset( $_GET['page'] ) ? $_GET['page'] : '';
    if ( 'wc-settings' === $page ) {
        return $recipient; 
    }
    if ( (float) $order->get_total() === '0.00' ) $recipient = '';
    return $recipient;
}
```